# Kill all instances of jboss on win xp

Tags: jboss

I want to kill all instances of jboss running on win xp
How can I do the same ?

Answer (score 5):

The smartest way to do this is (if you are using windows) install each jboss instance as a service, and then use net stop "Service Name". This can be easily automated via .bat file because you can just string all the net stop's together. More info on net stop: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490715.aspx

You can also use the taskkill feature if you know there are no other java.exe's out there.

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe /T
```

Otherwise use the shutdown port for each running instance. For AS7 you will use

```
%JBOSS_HOME%/jboss-cli.bat --connect command=:shutdown
```

Or other versions of JBoss have arguments to the bat file you can use.

```
%JBOSS_HOME%/./shutdown.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `jboss.bat stop`.

Or kill `java.exe`, but be carelfull not to close some other application.

Anyway, I doubt you have more than one instance.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to open Task Manager (or Process Explorer) and terminate the Java virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to Stop the JBOSS service from Administrative Tools->Services application ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<JBOSS_HOME>/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to avoid getting `Address localhost:1099 is already in use` error.

**First way:**

Goto **Task Manager** and select **Processes** tab.

Find the process named `Java(TM) Platform SE binary` and this represents `java.exe`

Select this **process** and **kill** it.

Now you are good to go with the JBOSS server. Start it.

**Second way:**

Go to **bin** **folder** in the `JBoss` location

E.g. (In my PC) - Windows 8, 8.1 and 10

```
D:\Servers\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin
```

Press **Shift** key in the keyboard and **right click**

Select Open Command Window Here

Then type, `shutdown.bat -S` and enter

It will take some to down the server and then you are good to go.